# The physics of a drying shirt

Tags: water, evaporation

So, I've noticed this enough times to state my observations.

I wash some shirts and hang them up to dry.  Sometimes I need to wear one before they have completely dried.

What I have noticed on every occasion is that one sleeve end is still a bit damp.  Not both of them, just one.  I am not sure, but the damp sleeve tends to be the one that has been hanging lower.

It's a bit odd, as I would have expected that both sleeve ends would be damp, but that does not seem to be the case.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Drying happens when dry air comes into contact with a wet surface. There are a lot of variables in that. The dryness of the air, the dampness of the material, different temperatures and sources of heat, currents in the air, flows in the water...

Nothing is more unlikely than "all things being equal" in the instances you have observed. Anyway, let's imagine a shirt hung to dry such that we control every factor we can think of. The hypothetical environment is graded and symmetric in all the expected ways.

A shirt hung slightly off level will put one sleeve lower than the other. What about this difference in altitude would result in a difference in the variables that contribute to drying?

Start with air qualities. If water vapor leaving the shirt tends to fall, the air surrounding the lower sleeve will be more damp because it is lower in the room. This might contribute.

How about heat sources? If cool air tends to pool lower in the room, the lower sleeve will hang in slightly cooler air and absorb less heat from the air, thereby taking longer to evaporate.

What about water flows? Moisture in fabric tends to spread out and down, tending toward the bottom edge even if it's not enough to form drips. This creates a gradient along the vertical axis. If one sleeve hangs lower in this gradient it will be a more attractive moisture sink for the garment as a whole. The low-hanging cuff will be the wettest part.

You can see all of this happening in a much simpler experiment. Wet several small towels and hang them to dry at different angles. Let us know what you find!

Comment: I think it is some kind of wicking action.  What is odd that wicking seems to tend to prefer one side or another.  There is never two damp sleeve ends.

Comment: Wicking creates a flow from wet areas to dry areas in hydrophilic materials like the fabric of your shirt. This force can be strong enough to counteract gravity. That explains wax flowing up a candle wick and it's the reason water doesn't run right to the bottom edge of a wet shirt. The water flow paragraph includes this concept ("tends to spread out") without mentioning its proper name, which you correctly identified as wicking. However, the force responsible for the lower sleeve's wetness is gravity. In the absence of gravity, wicking would spread the moisture evenly through the shirt.

Comment: What I am thinking is there is some kind of siphon action going on, which draws the water to the lower sleeve, leaving the slightly higher one completely dry.  The wicking functions to keep the water 'connected' and allow the shirt to act as a siphon.